# Getting QT to recieve serial data sent at 10Hz

Tags: qt, serial-port

I am fairly new to QT, and am involved in a project in which we are writing an application to receive data from multiple sensors via an X-Bee radio. I have been working with a test sensor and an Arduino Mega ADK. The Arduino is set up to receive data from the sensor, then forward it on via the serial port to my QT application.

I am currently able to receive this sensor data and am working to correctly store the data for the needs of the application. 
The problem is that I expect to receive one "packet" of data, but it appears the buffer has multiple pieces of data stacked up and ready to read.

How do I get my program to read one complete packet at 10Hz. I have been going over the examples, but none of them seem to deal with receiving data at a set rate. I am just looking for a tutorial or some code examples that show how to receive data at a particular interval.

(I have asked some bad questions in the past, so if this question is bad, please let me know how I can improve)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to control how data is sent rather than control how data is received. If the arduino keeps pushing data all the time it will be more awkward to try and isolate one of those many "packets" every 100 msecs.

So you need to make the arduino send one packet of data every 100 msecs, and from Qt you need to read in exactly the amount of bytes each "packet" is. If your "packet" size is uniform and fixed, then you can use a static size for it. If not, send the length of the packet first thing in every "packet".

It may still be possible to receive more or less data than you anticipate, in that case it is your responsibility to chop off or append in order to produce a single "packet".

Comment: thank you, this makes sense. So i should create a buffer in my application that is the size of my static length packet. when the buffer is full, grab the data in the buffer so the next packet can be captured?

Comment: Well, also remember not discard excess data, which will be forming the next packet.